# pymongo justOne & multi

Tags: pymongo

I have a database "testdb" with collection "testcol" which looks like this:

```
{u'_id': ObjectId('50eeb8029b75941b9af614bd'), u'birth': 1}
{u'_id': ObjectId('50eeb82e9b75941bc820f22c'), u'birth': 2}
{u'_id': ObjectId('50eeb82e9b75941bc820f22d'), u'birth': 3}
{u'_id': ObjectId('50eeb82f9b75941bce96032c'), u'birth': 2}
{u'_id': ObjectId('50eeb82f9b75941bce96032d'), u'birth': 3}
```

The code is like:

```
m_connection = MongoClient(M.HOST,M.PORT)
col = m_connection['testdb']['testcol']
#some_operation
cursor = col.find()
for doc in cursor:
        print doc
```

Im trying to update all the documents with birth higher than one,
so I replace some_operation with `col.update({'birth':{'$gt':1}},{'$set':{'death':'near'}},{'multi':True})` I get the error: `TypeError: upsert must be an instance of bool`

Similarly, I want to delete only one out of all the documents that have birth as 2 0r 3.
I replace some_operation with `col.remove({'birth' : {'$in' : [2,3]}},{'justOne' : 1})` I get the error: `TypeError: Wrong type for safe, value must be a boolean`

I tried using direct booleans in place of {} array, but only one document is update and all those with birth as 2 or 3 are deleted.

Just in case it has something to do with versions: I have pymongo-2.4.1 and Python2.7
Any clues where im going wrong??
Thanks a lot.

Edit:
The documentation says:
update(spec, document[, upsert=False[, manipulate=False[, safe=None[, multi=False[, check_keys=True[, **kwargs]]]]]])

Does it mean that: if i want to use 'multi'=True, i have to compulsarily go around defining values for whatever (upsert, manipulate, safe) comes before it?

Also, for remove, it says:
remove([spec_or_id=None[, safe=None[, **kwargs]]])
Where is the 'justOne' mentioned [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/delete/)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you use `multi=` in your call to `update()` (e.g., `col.update({'birth':{'$gt':1}}, {'$set':{'death':'near'}}, multi=True)`), Python will apply the default values for any optional arguments you omit. You can read more about this behavior at http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments

To your other question about `justOne`, unfortunately it does not appear as if PyMongo supports it yet. Currently the way to do this would be to use `find_one()` to get the document and then pass its `_id` to `remove()`.

Comment: conceptually, i understand all that u said, however none of these syntaxes work: `{'multi'=True}` or `{'multi':True}` or `{multi=True}` or `{multi:True}` or `multi=True` or `'multi'=True`... Either i get a syntax error, or it tries to assign 'upsert' to True

Comment: Using a dictionary won't work. And putting quotes around the name of a parameter will result in a syntax error. Did you try the example I gave you?